# Increase items count web-scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am a beginner with Scrapy framework and I have 2 questions/problems:

1. I made a "scrapy.Spider" for a website, but it stops after 960 elements retrieved, how can I increase this value, I need to retrieve about ~1600 elements .... :/
2. Is it possible to launch scrapy infinitely by adding a waiting time for each "scrapy.Spider"?

UPDATED

```py
class Spell(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    level = scrapy.Field()
    components = scrapy.Field()
    resistance = scrapy.Field()

class Pathfinder2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Pathfinder2"
    allowed_domains = ["d20pfsrd.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/spell-lists-sorcerer-and-wizard/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Recovering all wizard's spell links
        spells_links = response.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr/td/a[has-class("spell")]')
        print("len(spells_links) : ", len(spells_links))
        for spell_link in spells_links:
            url = spell_link.xpath('@href').get().strip()
            # Recovering all spell information
            yield response.follow(url, self.parse_spell)
        
    def parse_spell(self, response):
        # Getting all content from spell
        article = response.xpath('//article[has-class("magic")]')
        contents = article.xpath('//div[has-class("article-content")]')
        # Extract useful information
        all_names = article.xpath("h1/text()").getall()
        all_contents = contents.get()
        all_levels = RE_LEVEL.findall(all_contents)
        all_components = RE_COMPONENTS.findall(all_contents)
        all_resistances = RE_RESISTANCE.findall(all_contents)

        for name, level, components, resistance in zip(all_names, all_levels, all_components, all_resistances):

            # Treatment here ...

            yield Spell(
                name=spell_name,
                level=spell_level,
                components=spell_components,
                resistance=spell_resistance,
            )
```

There are total of 1600 links

`len(spells_links) :  1565`

**BUT** Only 953 scraped

```
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 2,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/404': 2,
 'item_scraped_count': 953,
```

I run spider with this command
`Scrapy crawl Pathfinder2 -O XXX.json"`

[CLI informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXGmk.png)

Thanking you in advance !

Comment: Can you also mention the `start_urls`?

Comment: Yep, I have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the amount of urls:

```
In [3]: len(response.xpath("//span[@id='ctl00_MainContent_DataListTypes_ctl00_LabelName']/b/a"))
Out[3]: 1073
```

So you have 1073 urls, each one of the, is a "spell" page, so you have a total of 1073 spells, not 2000.

After running your code I get this:

```
'downloader/request_count': 1074,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1074,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11368517,
 'downloader/response_count': 1074,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1074,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 31.657692,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 29, 7, 17, 2, 877042),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 31520000,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1074,
 'item_scraped_count': 1073,
```

It scraped 1073 so **no problem with the spider**.

**BUT** I removed this part:

```
all_levels = RE_LEVEL.findall(all_contents)
all_components = RE_COMPONENTS.findall(all_contents)
all_resistances = RE_RESISTANCE.findall(all_contents)
```

If you get errors check this part again.

[regex in python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

**EDIT:**

Some of the links appear more than once:
[image]

So the number of links is bigger than the number of items.